# Fetching json from MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to fetch some records from database in ASP.Net MVC and KnockoutJs.

Following is my controller method in MVC

```
public JsonResult FetchAccountCodes(string code = "")
        {
            var coaCode = db.ChartOfAccounts.Where(m => m.ACCOUNT_CODE.StartsWith(code)).Select(x => new { x.ACCOUNT_CODE }).ToList();
            return Json(coaCode, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
        }
```

and KnockoutJs code

```
self.selectedSubAccount.subscribe(function (newValue) {                
                var likeCode = newValue.substring(0, 2);
                var param = { code: likeCode };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/ChartOfAccounts/FetchAccountCodes",
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: param,
                    success: function (data) {                        
                        self.ACCOUNTCODES(data)
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert("Could not load the Account Codes" + error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
                    }
                });
                var accType = "Control";
                self.ACCOUNT_CODE(GenrateAccountCode(likeCode, accType));
            });
```

The problem is that ACCOUNTCODES observable array did not populated with the returned json.
and remains null.

Comment: did the values populate in 'coaCode' variable ?

Comment: What's the value of `data` in your `success` callback? Is it a simple array of objects, or is it an object itself with the array as a property?

Comment: yes Bilal, coaCode contains the values, i already checked while debuging.

Comment: and ebohlman, i could not get the value of data, however while debuging the KoJs code the value of observable array self.ACCOUNTCODES is shown as "object[0]".

Comment: Can you post the http response?  I think you have to drop the "ToList" at the end of your linq.

Comment: the KoJs debugger shows nothing in http response. and after dropping "ToList" i got the data. I have checked the http response, but the probelm is still there. the observable array still showing object[0]

Comment: Are you accessing the observable array as as self.ACCOUNTCODES()? That is, with parentheses?

Comment: Yes, i am accessing the observable as self.ACCOUNTCODES()

Comment: Can you please post the HTTP Response.  I just want to see if it is being returned as an array or an object.  Generally I do something like return JSON(new{data}) and then self.ACCOUNTCODES(data.data)

Answer (score 0):

When returning a list from the controller, I've found that sometimes I need to wrap the list in an anonymous object for things to work properly. The named property seems to help.

```
public JsonResult FetchAccountCodes(string code = "")
{
    var coaCode = db.ChartOfAccounts.Where(m => m.ACCOUNT_CODE.StartsWith(code)).Select(x => new { x.ACCOUNT_CODE }).ToList();
    return Json(new {AccountCodes = coaCode}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}


self.selectedSubAccount.subscribe(function (newValue) {                
            var likeCode = newValue.substring(0, 2);
            var param = { code: likeCode };
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/ChartOfAccounts/FetchAccountCodes",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                dataType: "json",
                data: param,
                success: function (data) {                        
                    self.ACCOUNTCODES(data.AccountCodes)
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("Could not load the Account Codes" + error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
                }
            });
            var accType = "Control";
            self.ACCOUNT_CODE(GenrateAccountCode(likeCode, accType));
        });
```

Comment: I have tested the above, suggested by Rob Ribeiro. The problem is still there.

Comment: Not sure why you're having issues with this. Have you tried it in a fiddle? I put this together and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/GF3kh/114/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Http Header:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:20613/ChartOfAccounts/FetchAccountCodes?code=21
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:__iswl_localhost:20613=0; __RequestVerificationToken=0rHILZnMkH6IJ7JK0CUF26vxcZP-RmuoZFGPHwhmQyGL_k_UCJCpxORbOQxUnyjVXeGLRZvG64ICgCb5B47Sqaqotbvin6snSg-ojWaLi7o1; instance0|session_id=%223bb6b256463042ada79bbec7934180ed%22; last_used_database=acompany; sid=7e671736a7a7fd3903a90716f2fc6d76c09e84a2; __iswl_localhost:20613=0; .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=HbluCWr03lY5R2jEvC_25yDkMMIrIXOrpajLFV2RJORdMAidF49lNH9tYhRGYc8KZpAJsolViQ3Igw5fc1vPoxGUwtWe3EXPWQCpcrVjtl6BzJ85CmMNNjF2hOQCSyIrT8bJHhEysirnH-c106mTe1LFT7bTyDeAsxhYxn1oPTqtLBzrY4uqtrywxclgveVP8gKmbhkeCRNLzPSShjUMbatAfHy7LirRsyTvqICntIIcci6tMKl8jQd8d65XhHgfKXmOFZGkHQTwdgqAWu2fb_6KkbK5fkoT9jXmgPZJ-8MeCLZ7dWQY7VygknXIgLHHu1mq2AX3ogXVuO0whb4DoqX6k8U_ac8G_4sM6djuPtF4vvrq89mkXSsx1UyJG-idMHzaPn8BziIRtamJP9cCLonyLszxSfuu-jSk1YAQcp1Az-28LUKNq7gFph3a23D3b0wMjJDwG1aqvnthfXYs_U93-FKw7u0JJO1FQkJBx2A
Host:localhost:20613
Referer:http://localhost:20613/ChartOfAccounts/Index
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
code:21
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:74
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 06 Feb 2014 13:34:45 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:5.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?RTpcUHJvamVjdHNcRG90TmV0XE1WQzVcVU1NSVRleHRpbGVcVU1NSVRleHRpbGVcQ2hhcnRPZkFjY291bnRzXEZldGNoQWNjb3VudENvZGVz?=
```

and Response:

```
 {"AccountCodes":[{"ACCOUNT_CODE":"21000000"},{"ACCOUNT_CODE":"21010000"}]}
```

this the array in http response